# Um método estático é realmente um método?

Tags: java, c#, terminologia, característica-linguagem, métodos-estáticos

Algumas linguagens, especialmente Java e C#, chamam de método estático o que normalmente seria uma função que executa algo, mas sem receber um objeto indiretamente como o método normal recebe.

Parece óbvio. Mas ele realmente é um método? Ele não seria só uma função, já que perde a característica de ter o `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é simples de responder isso. Não achei algo canônico.

De fato, a confusão faz sentido. Eu mesmo sempre chamei de função, mas analisando melhor tem uma diferença possível que eu acho que faz chamar de método, pelo menos nessas linguagens que operam desta forma. Venha comigo até o fim.

Em algumas linguagens as funções já possuem uma característica que me faz acreditar que ela é uma função especial e merece um nome diferente. Não sei se lá deveria ter um nome diferente, porque é algo que uma função normalmente não tem, mas ao mesmo tempo se todas as funções são assim, pode ser estranho.

O fato é que o método estático poderia ter uma espécie de `this`. Se ele acessa variáveis da classe da mesma forma que o método normal acessa variáveis do objeto, como ele faz isso? Um método normal tem um parâmetro oculto chamado `this` (que a linguagem permite acessar sem fazer referência a isso, pode acessar a variável do objeto de forma direta). Por que o método estático não tem isso e em vez de receber um objeto, recebe o contexto geral da aplicação, recebe os estados globais da classe? Poderíamos considerar que ele tem uma forma de `this`.

PHP, inclusive, chama isso de `self`. Não estou dizendo que foi uma sábia decisão, nem que foi ruim, mas mostra que alguém viu sentido.

Uma função costuma acessar variáveis que estão no escopo maior onde ela está inserida. Mas isso costuma valer para escopo de execução, o que uma classe não é, ela é estrutura de dados apenas.

E não podemos dizer que tem uma variável `this` porque isso implicaria uma passagem de parâmetro, que não ocorre de fato no método estático. Ao contrário do `this`, mesmo que usando implicitamente, que é uma variável, tem um objeto ali, referenciado como um ponteiro, o método estático só acessa o contexto externo de forma direta, nunca por uma variável extra. Ele faz sem indireção alguma, não tem ponteiro, nada.

Talvez faça sentido nessas linguagens chamar o "método de classe" de estático e não de função para manter o padrão, mas não seria errado se tivessem chamado de função ou "função de classe" para diferenciar de uma função mais global ainda (algumas pessoas dirão que toda função está em uma classe, ou até objeto em certas linguagens, só não está sendo mostrado na sintaxe).

De fato, não há uma definição que uma função não pode acessar dados externos, ela poda capturar contextos, e quando ela faz isso ela é chamada de não pura, mas ainda é uma função.

Pra mim um método estático é só uma função com efeitos colaterais com escopo limitado de onde **pode pegar estado global**. E essa última parte é onde alguns se apegam para dizer que é algo diferente. Também faz algum sentido, porque ao contrário da função que poderia capturar qualquer contexto externo dentro de onde ela está inserida, o tal método estático não.

C# mais moderno ajuda entender isso. Ela passou permitir variáveis globais fora de classe, para facilitar o *scripting*. No fundo tudo será inserido em uma classe pelo compilador, mas dá a ilusão de ser 100% global, e uma variável ali não pode ser acessada em um método em uma classe, mesmo estático.

Você pode alegar que no fundo estará dentro de uma classe, então é outro contexto e não é global de verdade, aí em qualquer lugar que permita ser modular uma função não acessaria a variável pelo contexto diferente. Mas não é a intenção mostrar assim. O fato de acabar dentro de uma classe gerada pelo compilador não é algo que o programador deveria saber, poderia até mudar um dia.

Então acho que não dá para concluir, e vamos continuar usando como sempre usamos, esperando que todos entendam da mesma forma. Se a documentação chama assim e todo mundo usa, vamos nela.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Realmente, essa é uma discussão que gera bastante debate entre os programadores. **Em geral, o que diferencia um método estático de uma função é que o método estático está relacionado a uma classe, enquanto a função não**. Ou seja, **o método estático faz parte da definição da classe, enquanto a função não**.

Por regra, eu costumo dizer que se faz parte da classe se chama **método**, e se não, então é **função**.

Em geral é correto dizer que um **método** é uma função que pertence a uma **classe** ou **objeto** e que pode acessar e manipular seus atributos, enquanto uma **função** não está necessariamente associada a um **objeto** ou **classe** específica. No entanto, é importante lembrar que a terminologia pode variar dependendo da linguagem de programação ou do contexto em que se está trabalhando. Em algumas linguagens, como o **C#**, por exemplo, é comum chamar qualquer função que pertença a uma **classe** de "**método**", independentemente de ela acessar ou não atributos da classe. Já em outras linguagens, como **JavaScript**, pode-se chamar uma função que esteja associada a um **objeto** de "**método**", mesmo que ela tenha sido declarada fora da **classe**, o que pode gerar **discução**, por **exemplo**, eu, que comecei com o **C#**, eu a chamaria de **função** por não pertencer a **classe**, independente do que esteja na documentação, este é meu modo de ver como citei no inicio. Portanto, é sempre importante verificar a convenção de nomenclatura adotada na linguagem ou no projeto em questão.

Se no **C#**, digamos que uma **função** passe ser gerada pelo **compilador** dentro de uma **classe**, então, por lógica, em tese, logo ela é um **método**, se por trás dos panos é compilado em uma **classe**, mesmo assim eu continuaria chamando de **função**, por que eu não escrevi dentro de uma **classe**, o que tambem pode gerar **discução**, e nos remeter ao **contexto** e eventualmente a **documentação** da linguagem em questão.

Quanto à questão do `this`, como você apontou, ele não está presente em métodos estáticos. **Na verdade, o que acontece é que os métodos estáticos não operam em instâncias específicas da classe, mas sim na própria classe em si**. Por isso, não faz sentido ter um "**this**", já que não há instância específica para se referir.

No **JavaScript**, é comum você declarar nas classes logo no **inicio do metodo** `const self = this;`, para poder usar o **this** dentro de funções aninhadas sem perder a referência da classe original.

Isso ocorre porque, em **JavaScript**, o valor de **this** pode mudar dependendo do contexto de execução da função. Em **funções aninhadas**, por **exemplo**, o valor de **this** pode se referir a um objeto diferente do objeto que chamou a função original.

Ao atribuir o valor de **this** a uma constante chamada **self**, é possível manter uma referência constante ao objeto da classe original, mesmo dentro de funções aninhadas. Dessa forma, o código pode continuar a acessar as propriedades e métodos da classe sem se preocupar com a mudança de contexto do **this**.

E ainda no **JS**, temos a **função anônima de autoexecução** de modelo **NAO ARROW FUNCTIONS** que é conhecida como **IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)**. Ela é utilizada para encapsular variáveis e funções em um **escopo local**, evitando assim que elas poluam o escopo global. A declaração "`const self = this`" é comumente utilizada dentro de **IIFEs** para preservar o valor de "**this**" e garantir que ele se refira ao **objeto** correto dentro do escopo local da função.

Enquanto no modelo **ARROW FUNCTIONS** não é possível utilizar a keyword "**this**" para acessar o objeto que chamou a função, já que ela é definida no momento de sua criação e não no momento de sua execução, o que pode gerar confusão na hora de lidar com o **contexto** de execução. É importante entender as diferenças entre esses dois modelos de declaração de funções e escolher o mais adequado para cada caso de uso.

**De qualquer forma**, como você também mencionou, o importante é seguir a documentação da linguagem que se está utilizando. Se a **documentação** chama de **método estático**, é assim que devemos nos referir a ele.